# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\cos (\pi x/2))}{1-x}$ without L'Hôpital's rule or Taylor series.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Having some trouble with this question and its really bugging me!

$$ \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\cos (\pi x/2))}{1-x} $$

I know I can solve this limit using L'Hôpital's Rule but I'm asked to solve the limit without using L'Hôpital's Rule (or Talyor series).

Many thanks.

Comment: What *can* you use?

Comment: As a matter of *definition*, this is the derivative of $\cos(\pi x / 2)$ at $1$.

Comment: Try with $$1-x=h$$

Comment: Okay thank you I will try doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As almost always,
I like limits
where the variable
goes to zero.

So, let
$x = 1+y$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\cos (\pi x/2))}{1-x}
&=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\cos (\pi (1+y)/2))}{1-(1+y)}\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\cos(\pi/2)\cos(\pi y/2)-\sin(\pi/2)\sin(\pi y/2)}{-y}\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{-\sin(\pi y/2)}{-y}\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi y/2)}{y}\\
\end{array}
$

If you know that
$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sin(y)}{y}
=1$,
then you are done
(with a little algebra,
because you can write
$\frac{\sin(\pi y/2)}{y}
=\frac{\sin(\pi y/2)}{\pi y/2}(\pi/2)
\to \pi/2
$).